# How can I prevent programs from using my mic without my permission?

Tags: windows, permissions, microphone, gaming

I am using Windows 10, and every time I am playing games like The Crew for instance, my mic volume gets lowered, as well as the sound.

I looked for a solution, and all I found was posts from 3 years ago saying that you can disable mic-adjustment on ubisoft, but this feature is no longer included..

Another thing I found was to go on settings and disable `"Allow apps to access your microphone"`, but this option also blocks apps like discord, and I don't want it.

Is there any way I can change the permission for such programs/games?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: One you **do** allow apps, then below you should get a list of **which** apps to allow. [I don't have win10 here to give any more detail]

Comment: @Tetsujin The list only includes windows 10 apps, but nothing more..